# How to sort entries by rubrics in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I do not know the wordpress very well, but I really need to understand the issue. The page displays a list of categories and at the bottom of the entry. When you click on a column, entries should be sorted, it works, but only the title is displayed, there is no link to the entry, and the picture and excerpt, date, segment.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz09r.jpg)

```
 <ul class="p-list">
                        <?php
                        if( $terms = get_terms( 'category', 'orderby=name' ) ) :
                            foreach ($terms as $term) :
                                echo '<li data-termid="'. $term->term_id .'">' . $term->name . '</li>';
                            endforeach;
                        endif;
                        ?>
                    </ul>

<?php
                    query_posts( array(
                            'post_type' => 'post'
                    ) );

                    if( have_posts() ){
                        while( have_posts() ){
                            the_post();
                            $i = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();

                            ?>
                            <div class="project">
                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><div class="project-img" style="background: url('<?php echo $i;?>')"></div></a>
                                <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                <p class="post-date"><?php the_date('d/m/Y'); ?></p>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        }
                    } else {  
                    }
                    ?>
```

here js code for sort

```
 $('#filter .p-list li').click(function(){
        var that = this;
        var filter = $("#filter");
        var datas = {
            action: 'myfilter'
        };
        if($('section').is('.may.blog')){
            datas['postcat'] = jQuery(that).data("termid");
        }else{
            datas['foliocat'] = jQuery(that).data("termid");
        }
        console.log(datas);
        $.ajax({
            url:filter.attr('action'),
            data: datas,
            type:filter.attr('method'),
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                filter.find('#response').text('Loading...');
              },
          success:function(data){
            $('#response').attr("data-curcat", jQuery(that).data("termid"));
            $('#response').html(data);
          }
        });
```

and functions.php

```
 function true_filter_function(){
        // для таксономий
        if(!empty($_POST['foliocat'])) :
            $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'folio_cat',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['foliocat']
            );
        endif;

        if(!empty($_POST['postcat'])) :
            $args['tax_query'][] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['postcat']
            );
        endif;

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if(!empty($_POST['foliocat'])) {
        if( $query->have_posts() ) :
            while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
                echo '<div class="portfolio"><a href="'.get_the_permalink(get_the_ID()).'"><div class="portfolio-img" style="background:url('.get_the_post_thumbnail_url().')"></div></a>';
                echo '<p>'. get_field('folio_desc') .'</p>';
                echo '<h4>'. get_the_title() .'</h4></div>';
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        else :
            echo 'No posts found';
        endif;


    }

    if(!empty($_POST['postcat'])) {
        if( $query->have_posts() ) :
            while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="project">
                    <div class="project-img"></div>
                    <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        else :
            echo 'No posts found';
        endif;
    }

echo '<div id="maxpagecat" data-maxpagecat="'. $query->max_num_pages .'"></div>';

    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'true_filter_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'true_filter_function');
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code and a summary of what you have tried so far to find & fix the problem. An image of the code is not helpful. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ok, insert code in question

Comment: This is only the code that displays the posts. What file is this code in and when does it get called? Where is the code that handles the sorting? We are nor mind readers - we need to see the relevant code in order to be able to help!

Comment: yes shure) sorry

Comment: In the `if` block `if(!empty($_POST['postcat'])) {` The only thing you are displaying is the title `<p><?php the_title(); ?></p>`... that could be why that's all that is being shown :)

Comment: Thanx so much :) now it works if copy/paste from 'foliocat'